# Find the nearest geo point

Tags: google-maps, route

I have a gps device that does not output very accurate gps positions.

How can I round those coordonates so that they will match the street course and not buildings etc ?

I want to draw a route on google maps but the line strikes buildings etc. I don't want that i just want a route on the street.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you are searching for is Map Matching. The point is, that you are not "rounding" the coordinates but searching for the nearest point on a street. There is no Google API that offers exactly that, but the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) offers a way to calculate a route with given [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints).

This Question on Stackoverflow describes a way to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404499/plotting-a-route-on-google-maps

I hope this helps,
B.